# Downloading source using Maven

Tags: java, scala, maven, pom.xml

I'm attempting to find the source for a particular sample project. The most I can find is a `POM` file which is located here: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.atmosphere%7Catmosphere-redis-demo%7C2.0.1%7Cwar

Can maven be used to pull down the source for this sample project so I can review it? New to Java tools and not sure if it's the right tool. What good is the POM for if you don't have the source? If you can use Maven to pull the source, what's the command line in order to do so?

Comment: Maybe you should rephrase your question.  It seems that you want to know where the source code is as a maven link (maybe)

Comment: Not sure what's going on here, but it looks like this particular project doesn't have any source code besides the POM. https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-samples/tree/9d9f8c275fac3193cd710a937705583e0054f059/extensions-samples/redis

Answer (score 0):

The WAR file of `atmosphere-redis-demo` that you are referring to is part of the samples, as said by Christopher Martin:

https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-samples/tree/9d9f8c275fac3193cd710a937705583e0054f059/extensions-samples/redis

It has only a POM file, which defines an overlay, i.e. another WAR (the [`jersey-pubsub`](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-samples/blob/caf890b7a37e4510925d7929f1a509ab3447dbac/samples/jersey-pubsub/pom.xml) WAR) being laid over the final WAR when `atmosphere-redis-demo` is built.

The `jersey-pubsub` WAR contains the Java files for which you're seeing class (`.class`) files in the final WAR of `atmosphere-redis-demo` (as well as some `webapp` stuff).

Overlays are a [cool feature](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) of the Maven WAR plugin. I've used it a lot to share common artifacts between WAR files, particularly stuff in `src/main/webapp`. I would not use it for Java class dependencies per se, since those can be managed with regular dependencies (pulled into `WEB-INF/lib` as JAR files), but Atmosphere seems to have a different stance on that (overlaying `.class` files onto `WEB-INF/classes`).

Answer (score 0):

Use the **maven-source-plugin** to download the source.

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>attach-sources</id>
        <phase>verify</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Any chance you can give me more detail, such as where to put that XML blurb you put followed by what maven commands to use?